# Dynamic DataTextField for DropDownList leads to StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, asp.net, stack-overflow

I tried setting the DataTextField for a DropDownList (that is bound to a datasource pointing to a database) in ASP.Net dynamically, so that I can access different columns in the database depending on the current localization.

However, the approach that I used leads to an infinite loop and eventually to a StackOverflowException, but I can't figure out why, as this approach seems to work well elsewhere (TextView etc.).

DropDownList:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlType" runat="server" DataSourceID="dtsType" DataTextField='<%# Localize("Name") %>' DataValueField="ID" OnDataBound="ddlType_DataBound">
```

Code of Localize():

```
public string Localize(string field)
    {
        string languageCode = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.ToUpper();

        if (languageCode.Equals("DE")) return field;

        return field + "_" + languageCode;
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure about reason. But you can have your localized text before data bound  and set your all retrieved localized in your datasource

Comment: I tried that before but that doesn't worf for datatextfields somehow. A compiler error arises when I try to set the binding in the resources

Comment: Did you get any exception while trying that approach?

Comment: what compiler error did you get ? Can you post the code with that approach?

Comment: strange, now it works!

Comment: a few days ago i got the message that a datatextfield was required at compile time

Comment: great to know. You need to set datatextfield  so that when binding, it would know what should be text or value. Shouldn't it be runtime error?

Comment: That was something what confused me too

Comment: oops that error occured when i tried to use the above code for an asp:BoundField. This failed at compile time, as BoundFIelds don't support databinding expressions. Still I don't know what caused the loop for the DropDownList